# How to SWITCH_SELECTION after Select Layer By Location in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-location

I have to use Geoprocessing tools in ModelBuilder.

My requirement is compare features in a Source personal geodatabase with those in a Target personal geodatabase and if the target personal geodatabase has extra captured features then to export them as a shapefile.

I am using Select Layer By Location tol first select all intersecting features in source and target personal geodatabases and then trying to switch selection in that same Select Layer By Location tool.

How can I SWITCH_SELECTION in the select in location Select Layer By Location tool?

[image]

Comment: i did as per your answer but process hang at select location (switch_selection)

Comment: Asking this as a new question like you have done at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146220/use-with-geoprocessing-tool-how-to-sitch-select is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should use each select operation one at a time.

- The first one, that is in your model should be defined as `NEW_SELECTION` only;
- Then use another Select Layer by Location (or by Attributes, it shouldn't matter) on the output of the first Selection, and choose `SWITCH_SELECTION` without defining any expression.

This should do the job.

EDIT: Further comments

The reason you do not see any selection in the output of your model is that you use `MAKE FEATURE LAYER` tool which creates a temporary layer within your model; thus in order to see the output you should export it to a new layer. You can use the `copy features` tool to export selected features. See result below (non intersecting polygons are populating a new layer and symbolized as hollow polygons with red border)

[image: Results with export]

This is the model I used:

[image: Model to export selected]

If you wish to only select features in your already existing feature class, you can drop the `Make Feature Layer` tool and preform selection directly on your layers. See results and model below (note that in order to see the selection on the view window you should zoom-in or out to perform rendering):

[image: Selection no Export]

and the model:

[image: Model no export]

Comment: Still my problem not solved first selection i have used NEW SELECTION and another select use select by attribute with SWITCH SELECTION but is not giving any results.

Comment: Does the first Selection (NEW_SELECTION) gives any selected features? Is it possible that all features in your feature layer intersect with a feature in your target building, i.e. if all are selected, than switch selection will unselect all.

Comment: @SATYA - If it helped you, you could mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the model that worked for me. Note that you have to turn your 'intersect' and 'switch selection' into TWO parts in the model. In my model I was intersecting the Feature layer with the outline of the United States. In the final step I used 'Copy Features' to create a feature class that will appear on my map.

[image: Model]

Comment: Sure thing! It took me awhile to figure it out myself.